# Why did my print fall off its raft?

Tags: troubleshooting, print-failure, rafts, monoprice-select-mini

I just set up a refurbished [MP Select Mini V2](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=29417) and tried to print the test file included by the manufacturer, `cat.gcode`, from the included SD card. I printed in PLA (I think; the unlabeled sample included with the printer) at the default extruder temperature, 190 °C. The print bed was set to 50 °C.

It appeared to print the raft fine, and then a couple of layers of the cat. At this point I walked away, and when I came back a few minutes later here's what I found:

[image: Printer with awful mess]

The raft is still stuck to the bed, but the layers of cat that were printed fell off the base and onto the floor. Here's what I picked up off the floor, (next to the detached raft):

[image: Raft and mangled print]

The raft was stuck on the bed just fine, so I don't think it's an adhesion issue. The bed and the desk the printer is sitting on are both very close to level (things don't slide or roll off). There's no breeze and I'm certain nothing bumped or touched the printer while it was running.

This is my first attempt at a print so I obviously have no idea what I'm doing. I'm planning to set up a camera to record the next attempt. What other troubleshooting can I do? What is the likely cause of this problem?

Comment: The question itself s good, but could you tell us some settings? What does the display, during print, say about temperatures? What material do you print (APS, PLA, Whatever)?

Comment: It looks like the print does not adhere too well to the raft, maybe you could slice a model yourself and try a calibration cube first; without the use of a raft. But a few more settings would be welcome. Please read ["Helpful Templates / Help us help you!"](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/helpful-templates-help-us-help-you), that might give you an idea. Welcome to 3D Printing.SE!

Comment: Did you try printing from an SD card to bypass computer issues, such as power saving, updates, etc.

Comment: @Trish I left the temperatures on the defaults, 190°C for the extruder and 50°C for the bed. The display indicated that temperatures were within a few degrees while I was watching. The material I believe is PLA (it came with the printer in an unlabeled pouch).

Comment: @PerryWebb I did print from an SD card, the one included with the printer.

Comment: @0scar I added the additional info from the template to my question. I assumed I'd have better luck printing the pre-made demo model first rather than trying to slice my own (so I could be incompetent at one thing at a time instead of two) but I'll try a calibration cube if you think that will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trouble lies within the presliced G-code: the temperatures are rather low for PLA and upping both by 10 degrees would be advisable:

- 200 °C for the Hotend
- 60 °C for the Bed

Atop that, printing a raft for PLA is usually not advisable.

Get yourself a slicer (the most common free ones I am comfortable with using are Cura, Slic3r and Slic3r Prusa Edition) and either import a fitting profile and create your own profile, then slice the `.stl`-model yoruself.

Comment: Thank you for this advice! I am a bit skeptical though. The file I used was literally designed by Monoprice to be the first file printed by new users on this printer, and I haven't found any complaints of problems similar to mine in forums for it, so that seems like an unlikely source of error.

Comment: @Robert there's a saying in 3D-printing: **never** use someone's else G-code, it will not suit your machine.

Comment: @Trish I think the presliced G-Code provided from the **manufacturer** of the machine should suit the machine.
Nevertheless the manufacturer assumes a well tuned, homed and calibrated machine.

Comment: I upped the temperatures as you suggested and tried again. It printed fine! I can't seem to print anything without a raft, but that's a separate problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as the model did not have enough surface contact with the raft.

---

This can be caused by to big of a gap between raft and model set in the slicer or because of Underextrusion. 
The part itself does not look underextruded, at least not a lot, so I would say that the slicer settings were not ideal.

I would suggest you slice a part by yourself and test the printer again.

From personal experience a skirt or brim works better with PLA and uncomplicated models.

For general bugfixing, explanation of slicer settings and anomalies the Simplfy3D hompage is a great resource.

Here is an article about [Rafts, Skirts and Brims](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/articles/rafts-skirts-and-brims/) and [here the general guide page for print quality.](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/print-quality-troubleshooting/)

---

Your printing temperature is a bit low but shouldn't be the cause for the problem. Maybe check the specs on the PLA you used.
Your bet temperature seems to be fine as the raft did adhere well.

---